# Fix include inline replace on integrated jquery plugin ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть плагин `ckeditor`, но работает подключение лишь in-line на страницу, если я перенесу нужные Файлы во внешний файл `libs.js`.

Ниже подключаю `common.js` - там вызову этот плагин ничего не работает, пишет `dir undefined`.

И путь не собирается. Kакже передать или собрать этот путь чтобы он увидел из `libs.js`?

Структура такая:

```
[App]-корень проекта 
 [js]
  libs.js
  common.js
 index.html
```

Как мне переопределять подключение файлов в плагине.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса  на английском зачем?

Comment: Предложите Ваш вариант названия(на английском короче,и возможно англоязычному сообществу пригодится),сути это не меняет,вопрос не решён.Зачем разводить off-top?

Answer (score 0):

**Разобрался господа.Может кому поможет, путем отладки выяснил что объект CKEDITOR.bathPath="/youpathfile/ckeditor/";
Почему то попадал адрес страницы, а не директория плагина.Почему я так и не понял.**